# Boolean If statement only returning outside

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

```
public static boolean stringToBoolean (String horv) { 
    if (horv == "H") {
        return true;
    } if (horv == "V") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

This is a small part of a program I am creating. The program is reading from a file and inputting the data into an array. For this part it is reading what will either be a "H" or "V" from the file and converting it to a boolean value. The problem is when I run the program I am only getting true for every value, even the ones that have a "V" as their variable.

Comment: You cannot compare Strings using the "==" operator.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses, I'm an idiot.

Comment: `==` checks whether objects references are same.

`.equals()` compares the values

Answer (score 2):

Change the code to be:

```
if ("H".equals(horv)) { return true; }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
public static boolean stringToBoolean (String horv) { 
    if ("H".equals(horv)) { // use equals method for string comparison 
        return true;
    } if ("V".equals(horv)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

String variables should be compared with equals() method in java.

Answer (score 1):

In `Java` you have compare `String` with a method `equals()` Like this

```
public static boolean stringToBoolean (String horv) { 
  if (horv.equals("H"))  return true;
  if (horv.equals("V"))  return false;
  return true;
}
```